# How many spanning trees does this graph contains?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How many spanning tree does below graph contains?

[image: image of graph]

I tried to calculate by using [edge deletion / contraction approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568358/finding-number-of-spanning-trees) and I am getting 48:

[image: edge addition deletion approach solution diagram]

I tried to calculate it by [Kirchoffs method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) as a determinant of Laplacian matrix:

$$ \left(\begin{matrix}2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&3&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&3&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{matrix}\right)
- 
\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}2&-1&0&0&-1&0&0&0\\-1&3&-1&0&0&-1&0&0\\0&-1&3&-1&0&0&-1&0\\0&0&-1&2&0&0&0&-1\\-1&0&0&0&2&-1&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&-1&3&-1&0\\0&0&-1&0&0&-1&3&-1\\0&0&0&-1&0&0&-1&2\end{matrix}\right)
 $$

I tried to calculate determinant of first co factor, which is Laplacian matrix [using wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7B3%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C3%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C-1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C3%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C3%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%7D%7D), and it was giving answer 116.

So, I was guessing which is correct answer and where did I make mistake?

PS: I dont have enough reputation to add images inline.

Comment: Should be 56, as in [OEIS A001353](https://oeis.org/A001353).

Comment: Deleting BF should get you $15+8=23$ msts.

Comment: yeah thats the exact mistake I did in deletion contraction approach. Whats wrong I did with Kirchoff's approach? (I dont have enough rep to upvote ur comment. You precisely pointed out my mistake.)

Comment: I made a mistake while entering cofactor in wolfram. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+{{3%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%2C0}%2C{-1%2C3%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C0}%2C{0%2C-1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C-1}%2C{0%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C-1%2C0%2C0}%2C{-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C3%2C-1%2C0}%2C{0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C3%2C-1}%2C{0%2C0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C2}}) gives correct answer of 56.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete BF and CG then you need to delete one of the remaining $8$ edges.

If you delete BF but not CG then you need to delete one of the $5$ edges of the LH cycle and one of the $3$ edges of the RH cycle. Similarly for deleting CF but not BF.

If you delete neither BF nor CG then  you need to delete one of the  $3$ edges for each of the LH and RH cycles and one of BC and FG.

$8+2\times 3\times5+ 3\times3\times2   =56 .$

Comment: yess that another approach. I really wanted to do it by deletion and contraction approach or kirchoff's approach, because with these approaches, I can solve for difficult graphs by hand. For example, some days back I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500267/quickly-finding-number-of-minimum-spanning-trees-in-given-graph) how can I apply your approach to complex graph and yet not have single answer. Also Morgan has pointed my mistake in deletion contraction approach. Can you please tell what I did wrong in Kirchoff's approach?